# how to solve the method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<FinancialTransaction,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Payment)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to save the data of payment in financial transaction but it gives me this error The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository is not applicable for the arguments (Payment) Please give me fast solution of this problem.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example: how do you class `Payment` and `Repository` look like, what do you execute to get the error etc.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.
The FinancialTransaction repository can do operations in financial_transaction table only.

If you are trying to save the payment while saving financial transaction.

Please do `one-to-one or one-many` mapping between these two entities.